# How to link to a specific post on the wall on FB from fbml

Tags: facebook, fbml

How can I create a link to a specific post on a wall from a FBML page? Like when you have a FB notification, click on it, and only the specific post (with its comments) is shown.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If you need to manually get a direct link to one specific wall post then just click on a time label under the post (the one that says how long ago this post was made) and it would go to a separated page for this post, which url you can copy and distribute.

If you need to generate this link automatically then when you post to a wall through API it should return your `post_id` that you would need to compose direct link.

Comment: nice! but this FB user experience is horrible

Comment: Brilliant :D Non-intuitive Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That "click the time to link a post" system is a really horrible non-intuitive user interface. They should revise that.

Comment: @Serg, it might be intentional. Sharing on FB increases the traffic on FB, but copying the url is global

Comment: I just tried it for a video- I had to right-click and do "open in new tab" or else the video player would just pop up, but I successfully have a link to just the post I wanted